# Laravel 8 Not identifying Method "tag()" when trying to use tags input

Tags: php, laravel, methods, tags, laravel-artisan

*Error Printed*: *"Call to undefined method App\Models\Skill::tag()"*

**Controller:**

```
    public function storeSkills(Request $request){
        $input = $request->all();
        $tags = explode(", ", $input['name']);
        $skill = Skill::create($input);
        $skill->tag($tags);
    }
```

**View:**

```
<input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" name="name" class="form-control" />
```

**Model**

```
   class Skill extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'skills';

    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

[Error Message (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2n3K.png)

[View Input (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOFWF.png)

Comment: please show us some more code. For example the Skill model

Comment: @MartinDimitrov I have updated my content with the query you requested

Comment: you haven't defined a `tag` method on that class ...

Comment: @lagbox
How to define?

Comment: I do not know what the tag function must do, but you have to define it in the model like this public function tag(){//somecodehere} inside the Skill class